# divide the y axis to make part with a score <25 occupies the majority in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I want to divide the y axis for the attached figure to take part with a score <25 occupies the majority of the figure while the remaining represent a minor upper part.
I browsed that and I am aware that I should use `scale_y_discrete(limits` .I used this  `p<- p+scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:20, labels = c(1:20,"//",40:100))` but it doesn't work yet.

I used the [attached data](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZEleLXZvFd9ywYv1hSKTtpsM1qe9yiwnfGk) and this is my code

**Code**

```
p<-ggscatter(data, x = "Year" , y = "Score" ,
             color = "grey", shape = 21, size = 3, # Points color, shape and size
             add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray"), # Customize reg. line
             add = "loess", #reg.line
             conf.int = T, 
             cor.coef = F, cor.method = "pearson",
            xlab = "Year" , ylab= "Score")
p<-p+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1980, 2020));p
```

[image]

Comment: ggplot2 doesn't support axis breaks (for reasons I agree with), but have you considered log- or sqrt-transforming your y-axis instead?

Comment: @teunbrand Thanks for your input. Is there any way around to produce the same plot in another package then? Th My senior colleague did not agree with transformation. Tanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is as close as I could get getting a fake axis break and resizing the upper area of the plot. I still think it's a bad idea and if this were my plot I'd much prefer a more straightforward axis transform.

First, we'd need a function that generates a transform that squeezes all values above some threshold:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# Define new transform
my_transform <- function(threshold = 25, squeeze_factor = 10) {
  force(threshold)
  force(squeeze_factor)
  my_transform <- trans_new(
    name = "trans_squeeze",
    transform = function(x) {
      ifelse(x > threshold, 
             ((x - threshold) * (1 / squeeze_factor)) + threshold, 
             x) 
    },
    inverse = function(x) {
      ifelse(x > threshold, 
             ((x - threshold) * squeeze_factor) + threshold, 
             x)
    }
  )
  return(my_transform)
}
```

Next we apply that transformation to the y-axis and add a fake axis break. I've used vanilla ggplot2 code as I find the `ggscatter()` approach confusing.

```
ggplot(data, aes(Year, Score)) +
  geom_point(color = "grey", shape = 21, size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", fill = "lightgray") +
  # Add fake axis lines
  annotate("segment", x = -Inf, xend = -Inf,
           y = c(-Inf, Inf), yend = c(24.5, 25.5)) +
  # Apply transform to y-axis
  scale_y_continuous(trans = my_transform(25, 10),
                     breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1980, 2020), oob = oob_keep) +
  theme_classic() +
  # Turn real y-axis line off
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

You might find it informative to read [Hadley Wickham's view](https://groups.google.com/g/ggplot2/c/jSrL_FnS8kc/m/MvzM_2_jiSIJ?pli=1) on discontinuous axes. People sometimes [mock](http://freerangestats.info/blog/2020/04/06/crazy-fox-y-axis) weird y-axes.

Comment: Thx a lot. That works. Appreciate your efforts and time. Upvoted.